# Ошибка python, PyQt5: RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qwebengineview

Недавно начал изучать *Python* библиотеку *PyQt5* (5.14.2) и решил написать небольшой браузер.

Я столкнулся с одной ошибкой:

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QPushButton has been deleted
> Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск).

Версия Python 3.6.
Вот код файла из Qt дизайнера:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(593, 397)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 30, 351, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 30, 41, 25))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:red;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 254, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 591, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 591, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
###
#        self.webView = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView = QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)                        # +++


        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 591, 291))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 593, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "search"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">>>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rm"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SBrowser"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

И вот код файла, где прописывается логика приложения:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import codecs
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from bro22 import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
def serch():
    i ='http://www.google.com/search?q='+ ui.lineEdit.text()
    print(i)
    ui.webView.load(QUrl(i))
    ui.webView.show()

def rm():
    pass
ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(rm)
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(search)
web = QWebEngineView()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно делать так:

```
import sys
import codecs
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from PyQt5.QtCore import *

#from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
#from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

#from bro22 import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(593, 397)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 30, 351, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 30, 41, 25))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"background-color:red;\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 254, 31))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 591, 21))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 591, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 67, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
###
#        self.webView = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView = QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)                        # +++


        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 591, 291))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 593, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "search"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">>>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rm"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SBrowser"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.rm)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.web = QWebEngineView()

    def search(self):                                              # - serch + search
        i ='http://www.google.com/search?q='+ self.lineEdit.text()

        print(i)
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl(i))
        self.webView.show()

    def rm(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = MainWindow() 
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

**main.py**

```
import sys
#import codecs
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from bro22 import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.rm)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)
#        self.web = QWebEngineView()

    def search(self):                                              # - serch + search
        i ='http://www.google.com/search?q='+ self.lineEdit.text()

        print(i)
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl(i))
        self.webView.show()

    def rm(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = MainWindow() 
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**bro22.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(728, 479)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.webView, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
        self.label.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label.setIndent(13)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 30))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 728, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SBrowser"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "rm"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите ключквое слово для поиска"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">>>"))


from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**bro22.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>728</width>
    <height>479</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QWebEngineView" name="webView" native="true"/>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>30</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeIncrement">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>12</pointsize>
          <weight>75</weight>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>SBrowser</string>
        </property>
        <property name="scaledContents">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="indent">
         <number>13</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>&lt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>rm</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>30</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="placeholderText">
           <string>Введите ключквое слово для поиска</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>50</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>&gt;&gt;&gt;</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>728</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebEngineView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qwebengineview.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov в качестве бонуса, я подправил ваш файл `bro22.ui`. Если вы считаете, что мои ответы помогают вам, вы также можете  отметить мой ответ как `Ответ полезен`.