# wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted каким образом можно решить?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qlayout

Столкнулся с проблемой

> wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted,

ошибка выходит либо после изменения в виджете, либо сразу при запуске.

После некоторого поиска решения нашел: [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339062/python-pyside-internal-c-object-already-deleted), [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914960/pyqt-runtimeerror-wrapped-c-c-object-has-been-deleted) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109872/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-python-pyqt5-runtimeerror-wrapped-c-c-object-of-type-qpushbutton-has). Но так и не понял Каким образом сделать так, что бы Qt не удалял объект, ведь у меня присутствует 1 центральный виджет, в котором находятся уже все остальные слои, виджеты.

Почему вообще изменение одного виджета приводит к его удалению, как это работает?

Вот примерный код который у меня есть:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QAction, QMainWindow,  QDesktopWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QLayout, \
     QFrame 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui  

 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        def first_tab():
            edits = QVBoxLayout()
            tablebox = QVBoxLayout()
            main_box.addLayout(edits,0,0,1,1)
            main_box.addLayout(tablebox,0,1,2,1)

            def edi():
                ed1 = QLineEdit()
                ed2 = QLineEdit()
                ed = (ed1,ed2)
                for i in ed:
                    edits.addWidget(i)
                return ed

            edit_list = edi()

            def table():
                qtable = QTableWidget(5, 5)
                for row in range(qtable.rowCount()):
                    box = QGridLayout()
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setLayout(box)
                    qtable.setCellWidget(row, 3, frame)
                    box2 = QGridLayout()
                    frame2 = QFrame()
                    frame2.setLayout(box2)
                    qtable.setCellWidget(row, 4, frame2)
                    col4 = QLineEdit()
                    box.addWidget(col4)
                    col5 = QLabel()
                    box2.addWidget(col5)
                return qtable, col4, col5
    
            create_table = table()[0]
            tablebox.addWidget(create_table)
            colmn4 = table()[1]
            colmn5 = table()[2]
            return edit_list, colmn4, colmn5

        first_tab()
        self.el = first_tab()[0]  #edit list
        self.column4 = first_tab()[1]  # edit 4 column
        self.column5 = first_tab()[2]  # label

        self.el[0].textChanged.connect(self.things)
        self.column4.textChanged.connect(self.things)

    def things(self):
        self.column5.setText(self.el[0].text()+self.column4.text()/100*2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я плохо понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать. Ваш код очень тяжелый.
Но я попробовал избавиться от ошибок, интуитивно следуя вашему коду.
Проверьте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QAction, QMainWindow,  QDesktopWidget, QHBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QLayout, \
     QFrame 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui  

 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        def first_tab():
            edits = QVBoxLayout()
            tablebox = QVBoxLayout()
            main_box.addLayout(edits, 0, 0, 1, 1)
            main_box.addLayout(tablebox, 0, 1, 2, 1)
            main_box.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
            main_box.setColumnStretch(1, 4)

            def edi():
                ed1 = QLineEdit()
                ed2 = QLineEdit()
                ed = (ed1, ed2)
                for i in ed:
                    edits.addWidget(i)
                return ed

            edit_list = edi()
            #print(f'edit_list = {edit_list}')

            def table():
                qtable = QTableWidget(5, 5)
                for row in range(qtable.rowCount()):
                    box = QGridLayout()
                    box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)            # !!! +++
                    
                    frame = QFrame()
                    frame.setLayout(box)
                    qtable.setCellWidget(row, 3, frame)
                    box2 = QGridLayout()
                    frame2 = QFrame()
                    frame2.setLayout(box2)
                    qtable.setCellWidget(row, 4, frame2)
                    col4 = QLineEdit()                     # col4
                    box.addWidget(col4)
                    col5 = QLabel('col5')                  # col5
                    box2.addWidget(col5)
# !!! +++                    
                    col4.textChanged.connect(
                        lambda text=col4.text(), column5=col5: self.things(text, column5))                    
                    
                return qtable, col4, col5
                
            create_table = table()  
            # print(f'create_table = {create_table}') 
            
            _table = create_table[0]
            tablebox.addWidget(_table)
            
# ???        colmn4  = create_table[1]
# ???        colmn5 = create_table[2]            
# ???        print(f'\n\tcolmn4={colmn4} \n\tcolmn5={colmn5}\n') 

        first_tab()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def things(self, text, column5):
        print(f'{text} -- {column5} ') 
# --------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--------------------------- ???
#        self.column5.setText(self.el[0].text() + self.column4.text()/100*2)

        try:
            _value = int(text)
            column5.setText(f'{_value / 100 * 2}')
        except:
            pass
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это почти то, что я хотел, но всё равно спасибо! Вы очень помогли. Подскажите что сложного в моём коде? Что именно вызывает затруднение при чтении?